# Can my server "download" files?

Tags: download, http, upload

I want my web server to fetch a file from another HTTP server. So that I do not need to download the file myself and upload it to my server.

Is this possible?

Comment: A lot more information is necessary here.  Yes it is possible, some devices as simple as a NAS box support torrent downloading.  How to implement this service would depend on a lot of things, the very least would be what OS you're running.

Comment: Depending on what you're trying to do, this might be more appropriate for Stack Overflow, as it could involve extensive programming. Once we find out more about your exact situation, we may want to consider moving it to Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 2):

Absolutely. Either ssh in and use wget or curl, or write a server-side script in e.g. PHP that performs the download.

Comment: I would add that the filesize is important. A server-side php script trying to download a huge file will fail when hitting the `max_execution_time` limit, so either this setting will have to be tuned, or dodged by using wget as background process, like this: exec('wget URL&')